# Binary search: weird middle point calculation

Tags: python, algorithm, search

Regarding calculation of the list mid-point: why is there

```
i = (first +last) //2
```

and `last` is initialized to `len(a_list) - 1`? From my quick tests, this algorithm *without* `-1` works correctly.

```
def binary_search(a_list, item):
    """Performs iterative binary search to find the position of an integer in a given, sorted, list.
    a_list -- sorted list of integers
    item -- integer you are searching for the position of
    """

    first = 0
    last = len(a_list) - 1

    while first <= last:
        i = (first + last) / 2

        if a_list[i] == item:
            return '{item} found at position {i}'.format(item=item, i=i)
        elif a_list[i] > item:
            last = i - 1
        elif a_list[i] < item:
            first = i + 1
        else:
            return '{item} not found in the list'.format(item=item)
```

Answer (score 3):

The last legal index *is* `len(a_list) - 1`.  The algorithm *will* work correctly, as `first` will always be no more than this, so that the truncated mean will never go out of bounds.  However, without the -1, the midpoint computation will be one larger than optimum about half the time, resulting in a slight loss of speed.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the case where the item you're searching for is greater than all the elements of the list. In that case the statement `first = i + 1` gets executed repeatedly. Finally you get to the last iteration of the loop, where `first == last`. In that case `i` is also equal to `last`, but if `last=len()` then `i` is off the end of the list! The first `if` statement will fail with an index out of range.

See for yourself: https://ideone.com/yvdTzo

You have another error in that code too, but I'll let you find it for yourself.

Comment: do you mean / instead of // ?

Comment: @filemonczyk no, because the `/` would be perfectly fine in Python 2. Try a few test cases for yourself and see what happens.

Comment: I just noticed it tends to skip the last return if while predicate is not match and results in returning 'None' which i suppose is null in python. eg binary_search([], 0). Did not manage to get any runtime errors

Comment: @filemonczyk yes that was it! Question, when would the code after the final `else` be executed?

Comment: now when Im reading the code it looks like it never gets executed since a number can be equal, more or less to specific value,